# How can I find the presentation of the hyperplane in a linear system?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Consider the family:
$$
\begin{matrix}
X & = & \textbf{Proj}\left(\frac{\mathbb{C}[s,t,u][x,y,z]}{s(x^4 -y^2z^2) + t(x^2y^2 - z^4) - u(x^4 + y^4 + z^4)}\right) & \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow\\
B & = & \textbf{Proj}(\mathbb{C}[s,t,u])
\end{matrix}
$$
How can I find the hyperplane $H_x \subset B$ of points whose fibers contain a point $x \in X$? For example, let $x = [0:1:1:1:(-1)^{(1/3)}:(-1)^{(1/3)}]$. For reference, I am looking at Nicolaescu's introduction to morse theory (page 252).

---

For reference, here is what I have tried: if I have the point $[s:t:u:a:b:c] \in X$, then I think the hyperplane will be spanned by the set of points
$$
\{s,t,u \in \mathbb{C}: s(a^4 - b^2c^2) + t(a^2b^2 - c^4) + u(a^4 + b^4 + c^4)\}
$$
I am guessing this because of the statement afterwards
$$
H_x = \{ P \in U : P(x) = 0 \}
$$
where $U$ is the projective plane parametrizing this family, but I am not sure why this is true.

Comment: If someone has enough reputation, can they add a linear system tag?

Comment: There is only a nonlinear system tag.

Comment: If that is the right one, will do. Actually, I think it has already been done by someone else.

Comment: Nonlinear systems are a far distance from algebraic geometry...

Comment: In fact, the more appropriate tag is [tag:divisors]. I'll add it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the fiber over $[s:t:u]\in B$ contains $x=[s':t':u':a:b:c]\in X$ then this means that, denoting by $P$ the equation of $X$ you wrote :

$$[s:t:u]=[s':t':u']\text{ and }P(s',t',u',a,b,c)=0.$$

In fact, by definition of $X\to B$, the fiber over $[s_0:t_0:u_0]\in B$ is 
$$\{[x:y:z]\in \Bbb P^2(\Bbb C) : P(s_0,t_0,u_0,x,y,z)=0\}\subseteq \mathrm{Proj}(\Bbb C[s_0,t_0,u_0][x,y,z])\subseteq \mathrm{Proj}(\Bbb C[s,t,u][x,y,z]).$$

So, what you wrote is almost correct : I would write $H_x=\{ [s:t:u]\in \Bbb P^2(\Bbb C) : s(a^4 - b^2c^2) + t(a^2b^2 - c^4) + u(a^4 + b^4 + c^4)\}$ instead of $\{ s,t,u\in\Bbb C : \dots\}$.

**Edit:** Now, denoting by $\hat{U}$ the dual projective space of $U$, if we want to describe explicitly the map $X\to \hat{U}$ defined by $x\mapsto H_x$, we can write it in coordinates. For this purpose, note that if $(As+Bt+Cu=0)$ is the equation of a hyperplane $H$ of $\text{Proj}(\Bbb C[s,t,u])$, then the coordinates of $H$ in $\hat{U}$ are $[A:B:C]$.

Hence, in your example, the map $x\mapsto H_x$ is defined by
$$[s:t:u:a:b:c]\mapsto [a^4 - b^2c^2:a^2b^2 - c^4:a^4 + b^4 + c^4].$$

Comment: This doesn't entirely answer the part of the question I raised in the bounty message.

Comment: In fact, I don't understand very well what you wrote here. What is "the vanishing locus of the hyperplanes"? (i.e. what does mean "vanishing" for a hyperplane?) Moreover, I don't know the definition of the "modification" of a linear system (and I don't have Nicolaescu's notes).

Comment: This is on page 212 of http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Morse2nd.pdf

Comment: Ok, thanks, and what's your problem with the definition of "modification"?

Comment: There is a lot of jumping around with information. I think the computation I was doing above was computing a correspondence between $X$ and $U$ not $\hat{U}$. I'm not sure how to figure out this morphism to the dual variety.

Comment: I edited my answer in order to describe the map $X\to \hat{U}$.